# JBoss CLI - undeploy by pattern matching

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I'm trying to write a script that would automatically deploy apps to JBoss. The problme is that my ear files have version in them. For example, myApp-1.0.1.ear or myApp-1.0.2.ear. Therefore, I'd like to be able to undeploy by pattern matching - 'myApp-.*.ear' Is it possible using JBoss CLI?

Answer (score 2):

```
jboss-cli.sh -command=undeploy | grep <your regexp> | xargs ...
```

-

```
jboss-cli.sh -command=undeploy
```

will show you the list of all your deplyments

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the following solution on my project:

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command="undeploy $(echo /tmp/myApp*)"
```

This command takes application for example myApp-1.13.war from /tmp directory and does deploy to JBoss.

You will be also able to apply this solution for deploy command.